# Why are we using Heisenberg equation of motion for non-observable $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, time-evolution

The author in one of my textbooks derived the time dependency of $a(t)$ and $a^{\dagger}(t)$ through the equation of motion. Is that allowed?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's allowed; if you look at the derivation of the Heisenberg equation, it holds for any operator, observable or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can e.g. argue that if [Heisenberg equation of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) holds for the Hermitian operators/observables $a+a^{\dagger}$ and $i(a^{\dagger}-a)$, it should also hold for $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ by $\mathbb{C}$-linearity.